# Pass object property through function parameter for if statement

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I have an array of objects.
I need to create 1 function that returns a specific object key name for an if statement. I am currently attempting to do this like so:

```
<button onclick="isClick('curly_hair')"><u>curly</u></button>
```

Here is the function I am attempting:

```
function isClick(value) {
    for (i = 0; i < People.length; i++) {
        if (People[i].options.value) {
//do stuff
}
```

Here is my array of Objects

```
var People = [
    {
        name: "Bill",
        img: "images/168-Cool-avatars/256x256_male-avatars_png/avatar-m-small-01.png",
        options: {
            curly_hair: false, long_hair: true, ...
        },
    },
```

To elaborate: Instead of needing to create an "if" statement for each of my "option" properties (curly_hair, long_hair, etc.) I am trying to pass this through the function parameter instead.
If I pass "isClick(curly_hair)", I want to return all Objects within the Person array that has curly_hair: true.

Comment: you can use Array.filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As value is a variable we can use with `[]` instead of `.` operator try this way

```
function isClick(value) {
    for (i = 0; i < People.length; i++) {
        if (People[i].options[value]) {
            //do stuff
        }
}
```

This is better to use filter also if needed.

```
function isClick(value) {
      return People.filter(function(obj){
        return !!obj.options[value];
     })
}
```